# URL Rewrite with Tomcat not working

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration

I used apache 2.2.9 in front of tomcat(through mod_jk) which has a ROOT folder and some .html files under webapp.

I configure URL rewrite in default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 3
    </IfModule>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.megamadz.com
    ServerAlias megamadz.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/tomcat/webapps
    JKMount /* ajp13_worker

    ...
    AllowOverride All
```

I placed .htaccess under webapps and ROOT, but rewrite.log has 0 output, whatever I typed in the browser, http://mydomain/about-us it says the ... is not available, it never point to http://mydomain/about-us.html

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^about-us$              about-us.html    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you try `RewriteRule    ^/about-us$              about-us.html    [NC,L]
`

Comment: Same, 404, 0 rewrite.log, here is the .htacess: RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^/about-us$             about-us.html    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^/advertising$         advertising/advertising.html    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^marketing$            marketing/marketing.html      [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^advertising-platform?$       advertising-platform/advertising-platform.html     [NC,L]

Comment: Do you have some entried in rewrite.log?

Comment: No, 0 byte, I do not know what's wrong.

Comment: Can you try to add the commands in yout http.conf (not in .htaccess)?

Comment: Same, nothing output

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying can never work. `JKMount /* ajp13_worker` means all requests are forwarded to Tomcat instead of being handled by Apache. Because Apache doesn't handle the request it also won't process the `.htaccess` file.

The way things are right now you should do the rewriting in Tomcat. If that's not what you want to do you should move your rewrite rules into the virtual host so they will be processed.

But it looks like you are trying to rewrite for static files, but you have a setup where basically every thing is handled by Tomcat. Perhaps you actually need something like `JKMount /someApp`, creating a scenario where Tomcat only handles the request for the web application and Apache serves the static files.

Comment: When I rewrite with dashes(-) between the path: ,/mobile-ad-with-video/... the browser takes it out. How do I prevent it to take out the dashes?